# Rendered attribute executing before button action

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.1

I have two view htmls(V001 & V002) both of which are to be rendered using the same jsf page. There is a continue button in my JSF Page which performs the action of storing the V001 DOM in Cache and fetches the V002 from Content server and displays it to the user. This is achieved through a managed bean.

In view V002, I have a button which I need to be rendered based on whether the view is V002 or not.

However the issue is the rendered condition is executing before the continue action and hence always evaluate to false since the view change from V001 to V002 happens only when the continue button action is executed.

NB: My bean is request scoped and I am using JSF 1.1

Comment: You have to provide file codes..

Comment: From one of the 'close' reasons: _"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]"_